# Importing h5py is giving numpy attribute error?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, h5py

When I am importing from kuti package, it triggers an import h5py which is causing me a lot of grief! It is giving me an attribute error: "module 'numpy' has no attribute 'typeDict'"

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/ack253/neuroaesthetics/ava-mlsp/predict_mlsp_wide.ipynb Cell 5 line 2
1 import pandas as pd, numpy as np, os
----> 2 from kuti import image_utils as img

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kuti/**init**.py:8
5 import warnings
6 warnings.filterwarnings('ignore',category=FutureWarning)
----> 8 from . import generic, tensor_ops, image_utils, generators, model_helper, applications
10 # remove tensorflow warnings
11 import logging

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kuti/generic.py:10
8 import numpy as np, pandas as pd
9 import multiprocessing as mp
---> 10 import os, scipy, h5py, time, sys
11 import urllib, shutil, subprocess
12 from munch import Munch

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/h5py/**init**.py:46
37     _warn(("h5py is running against HDF5 {0} when it was built against {1}, "
38            "this may cause problems").format(
39             '{0}.{1}.{2}'.format(*version.hdf5_version_tuple),
40             '{0}.{1}.{2}'.format(*version.hdf5_built_version_tuple)
...
318     return Tester
--> 320 raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
321                      "{!r}".format(**name**, attr))

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'typeDict'

[Here is a screenshot of my code:  ]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyNhh.png)

Answer (score 0):

It will be a version problem with the version of h5py you are using.

np.typeDict is a deprecated alias for np.sctypeDict and was removed after numpy 1.21.

A likely quick fix would be to install a specific version that supports it:

`pip install numpy==1.21`

However, you likely have other modules that use a newer/up to date version. I don't know which version of h5py you have but it's possible that just updating that would resolve it:

`pip install --upgrade h5py`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried that, but I am still receiving the same errors and now my terminal is saying this: ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
kuti 0.9.8.1 requires h5py<3.0.0,>=2.10.0, but you have h5py 3.10.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.13.1 requires numpy<=1.24.3,>=1.22, but you have numpy 1.21.0 which is incompatible.

Comment: Are you doing this in a virtual environment? It sounds like you've got lots of packages from different sources. Because package management is a nightmare with Python you should give application its own virtual env that way its dependencies are isolated from one another.

Based on the file name too, I think you're trying to run https://github.com/subpic/ava-mlsp/blob/master/predict_mlsp_wide.ipynb - just as an FYI that repo appears to use Python 2.7 and some pretty old versions of tensorflow and keras. So you'll likely have to pip install specific versions of any other imports from the time